# DIV Broken when i use <form>

Tags: html, css

Is that standard of DIV/CSS ? Why when i put `<form>` my `<div>` broken?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .header {
        background-color: #e3f2ff;
        width: 980px;
        border: 1px solid #666;
    }
    .main {
        width: 980px;
        border: 1px solid #666;
        height: 300px;
    }
    .left {
        background-color: #FFC;
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
    }
    .cen {
        background-color: #0FF;
        float: left;
        height: 300px;
        width: 578px;
        border-right-width: 1px;
        border-left-width: 1px;
        border-right-style: solid;
        border-left-style: solid;
        border-right-color: #666;
        border-left-color: #666;
    }
    .footer {
        background-color: #e3f2ff;
        width: 980px;
        border: 1px solid  #666;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

<body>

<center>
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <form action="home.php" method="post">
Username:<input type="text" name="username"/>
Password:<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="smbit" value="Login">
</form>
<a href="register.php">Not Register?</a>
<div class="cen"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  Copy Right
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be more explicit with what you want and where to be positioned in order to get the proper answer. Wayne's answer was good, if you want it in the right div then put it inside the second left div. You can not expect for an element to display in that div if you let it outside of it.

```
    <center>
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="main">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="cen"></div>
    <div class="left">
    <form action="home.php" method="post">
    Username:<input type="text" name="username"/>
    Password:<input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="smbit" value="Login">
    </form>
    <a href="register.php">Not Register?</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    Copy Right
    </div>
    </center>
```